# Is there a way to compare regular expression backreferences?

Tags: regex, grep

I have the following sample expression that I'm passing to egrep over a word list:

```
^([a-z])lu([a-z])\2er$
```

I'd like to further stipulate that the content of \1 and \2 must be different, e.g. this would match "bluffer" but not "blubber". Is there a way to build this into the expression itself (so I can get my results right from egrep or something like it), or am I stuck doing this in some real language with regular expression support and manually checking that none of my groups are the same?

Comment: sorry, I now just see you included egrep in your question from the beginning! I have removed my answer therefor.

Comment: You didn't have to! I'm not wedded to egrep, it's just what I've been experimenting with on the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something more powerful.  Regular expressions can't track state.  [Sed](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-7) could probably do what you need.

Answer (score 3):

You could add the negative lookahead `(?!\1)` in front of the 2nd match group. The following regex:

```
([a-z])lu(?!\1)([a-z])\2er
```

matches `"bluffer"` but not `"blubber"`. This only works properly if both the groups match the same amount of characters.

Comment: I imagine this gets ungainly with additional groups, though. I tried to keep the example short, but in principle I'd like to specify some arbitrary number of groups, where \1, \2, \3, ..., \n would all be different. I guess you could say (?!\1|\2|...|\n-1) or something. What tool supports the syntax above? egrep didn't take it.

Comment: @twon33, yes, you could do `(?!\1|\2|\3...)`. But not with egrep, which has POSIX regex support (and does not support any look-arounds). See this [comparison-table](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html) to see which languages/tools do support it.